# How to connect apache2 to php from different server

Tags: php, apache2

I want to connect apache2 to php. Let's suppose I have two servers, server1 with apache and server2 with php.

How to connect both services with each other?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on why you don't just install Apache2 and PHP on the same server? What's the use case?

Comment: Use FastCGI. PHP-FPM (PHP FastCGI Process Manager) is what you want to look for. If you're asking for a guide or tutorial, StackOverflow is not the right place.

Comment: i install apache on server1 and install php to server2 i just want to connect them with each other